# comma vs. colon

Tags: semicolons

Should I use a comma or a semi-colon to connect these two sentences?

> In addition to my education, interpersonal skills and work experience,
>   my previous experience at XXX gives me insight into the brand.

or

> In addition to my education, interpersonal skills and work experience;
>   my previous experience at XXX gives me insight into the brand.

Comment: Can someone advise which sentence is correct...the first or second with semicolon?

Comment: Semicolons _must_ have complete, related sentences on either side. Colons only require _one_ complete sentence. Commas have their own rules. Basically: it's up to you on using a colon or semicolon in your example, however you probably want a conjunction if using a comma. You could also nix the comma/colon and just say "because my previous experience..."

Comment: The version with a semicolon is ungrammatical (because what precedes the semicolon isn't a complete sentence). Using a colon instead makes no sense --- the resulting sentence doesn't match what colons are used for.  Use a comma.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the body of your question. I suspect you didn't mean to use *colon* in your title.

Answer (score -1):

@VampDuc is right about the theory, but wrong in the conclusions he reaches. The semi-colon makes no sense. There is no complete sentence on its left hand side. If you have put in the semi-colon because you thought that the sentence was getting too long, then it would be better to write two sentences. The first sentence would be about your personal characteristics. The second about the understanding you would bring to the brand.

By the way, writing as a former employer and hence recruiter, your sentences, with or without the semi-colon, would not impress me at all. Generalised boasts about your education, inter-personal skills etc cut no ice. And don't talk to me about insight into MY brand, which I have nurtured for many years (for all you know). But all that would be a subject for a different site.

Comment: I agree the colon would be wrong, but since the question included a colon as an option originally, I included its use. The edit to the question also makes my advice weird...

Comment: My only edit was to take out the name of company and replace with XXX.

Comment: @VampDuc I sympathise: edits can make nonsense of well-considered answers to previous versions of the question.

Comment: @user336195 Eh, somehow the company name made it more explicit that it was in direct correlation. English is weird.

Comment: It would be courteous for down-voters to explain why.